# Get the datetime in C

Tags: c, datetime

I know that with the usage of ctime like this

```
time_t now;
time(&now);
fprintf(ft,"%s",ctime(&now));
```

returns me the datetime in this way

```
Tue Jun 18 12:45:52 2013
```

My question is if there is something similar with ctime to get the time in this format

```
2013/06/18 10:15:26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [strftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
  struct tm *tp;
  time_t t;
  char s[80];

  t = time(NULL);
  tp = localtime(&t);
  strftime(s, 80, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", tp);
  printf("%s\n", s);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this one works fine. The only problem is that I used it in a while loop and it returns me in every loop the same time. How can I modify it to return me the new time in every loop? Using memset maybe?

Comment: Then you have to call time() and localtime() on every loop

Answer (score 1):

See the manpages for [localtime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) and [strftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime). The first function converts the timestamp in a structure with the date/time elements, the second converts that to a string using a format string.

Answer (score 0):

Broken-down time is stored in the structure tm which is defined in  as follows:

```
       struct tm {
           int tm_sec;         /* seconds */
           int tm_min;         /* minutes */
           int tm_hour;        /* hours */
           int tm_mday;        /* day of the month */
           int tm_mon;         /* month */
           int tm_year;        /* year */
           int tm_wday;        /* day of the week */
           int tm_yday;        /* day in the year */
           int tm_isdst;       /* daylight saving time */
       };
```

It is possible to display individual variables in the format we desire to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void){
    FILE *ft = stdout;
    char outbuff[32];
    struct tm *timeptr;
    time_t now;
    time(&now);
    timeptr = localtime(&now);
    strftime(outbuff, sizeof(outbuff), "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", timeptr);//%H:24 hour
    fprintf(ft,"%s", outbuff);
    return 0;
}
```